# iOS / Swift Can't add gesture to child class

Tags: ios, swift, gesture

I'm writing an child class but couldn't add gesture recognize for it.
Selector error. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class Alert: KeyboardViewController {

    var AlertContainer = UIView()

    func ShowAlert(message: String,view: UIView)
    {
        var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("CloseAlertView"))
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        AlertContainer.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        AlertContainer.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        AlertContainer.userInteractionEnabled = true
        AlertContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x000000, alpha: 0.8)
        view.addSubview(AlertContainer)



var CTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: AlertContainer, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        var CRight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: AlertContainer, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        var CLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(item: AlertContainer, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        var CBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: AlertContainer, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        view.addConstraints([CTop,CRight,CLeft,CBottom])
    }

    func CloseAlertView() {
        AlertContainer.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

But when i tap on to this view, error: exc_bad_access or some time **unrecognized selector sent to instance**. Really don't know why ?
and one more question that i can't access to parent class view by super.view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you are calling this class in the following way (if not ignore my answer)?

```
// wrong implementation
func myFunc() {
    var a = Alert()
    a.ShowAlert("Message", view: view)
}
```

The previous code is wrong (and causes BAD_ACCESS) because `a` does not exists anymore after the function finished. So when the gesture is fired, it acts on nothing and crashes.
Solution:

```
var a = Alert()  // a property of the caller class

func myFunc() {
    a.ShowAlert("Message", view: view)
}
```

In this way the life of `a` is long enough to wait for the gesture.

Comment: Yes, i'm calling subclass by the first way. That's weird, i'm using PHP and it's ok with it, but failed with swift? I just tried to fixed my code but there is other error occurred: EXC_BAD_ACCESS at `var AlertContainer = UIView()` ?

Comment: mmh, I tried the code and was ok after my fix, how is KeyboardViewController declared?

Comment: It's an rootviewcontroller. the first file in my extension. `class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {`

Comment: `Alert` is subclass of `KeyboardViewController`

Comment: If `Alert` is not a subclass of `KeyboardViewController` i can define subclass outside of function block the way you said, however still error with selector with gesture :(:  `*** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7a791730 of class 'abc.Alert' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[abc.Alert CloseAlertView]`

Comment: The problem is that Alert extends KeyboardViewController and KeyboardViewController instantiates Alert. This causes an infinite loop. Try to change your subclassing logic.
Besides, remember that to use your gesture recognizer (and methodSignatureForSelector in particular) Alert must extends a Cocoa class. It seems to me that a right superclass for Alert is UIView; "Alert : UIView".

Comment: Like i said, if `Alert` is not a subclass of `KeyboardViewController` is still error. Or if `Alert` is subclass of `UIView` is still error too . EXC_BAD_ACCESS . I'm really crazy about it, and don't know how to handle with gesture recognizer :( can you suggest any code?

Comment: Tks, it's working now. i put declare `Alert` outside of func and put `Alert` subclass is an child of `UIView`. But other question is how can i access to parent view by super.view if Alert is not an subclass of `KeyboardViewController`?

Comment: Hi, SO does prefers not to have too long comments, please begin another SO question. I will be happy to reply there.